Why does "left shift count >= width of type" seemingly kick in late?
For context, I on a 64-bit (AMD64) little-endian system and am using g++ -std=gnu++23 -O3 -Wall to compile my code, if it makes any difference.
The following code snippet all shows some seemingly pathological behaviour: the warning "left shift count >= width of type" kicks in later than I would expect (partially explained here), but does not seem to do full integer promotion as I would expect either.
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // any value will cause the confusing behaviour, of course
  uint8_t a = 5;
  a <<= 7;
  // 128, as expected
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(a) << '\n';

  uint8_t b = 5;
  b <<= 8;
  // 0, as expected, if slightly dubious (8 = width of type, right?)
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(b) << '\n';

  uint8_t c = 5;
  c <<= 16;
  // 0, as expected, assuming a promotion to a larger unsigned int type
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << '\n';

  uint8_t d = 5;
  d <<= 31;
  // 0, as expected, assuming a promotion to a larger unsigned int type
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(d) << '\n';

  uint8_t e = 5;
  e <<= 64;
  /*
    raises a warning, rather understandably
    (I suppose it isn't aware of __uint128_t?)
  */
  // still outputs 0, although I assume this is undefined behaviour
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(e) << '\n';

  uint8_t f = 5;
  f <<= 32;
  /*
    raises a warning for some reason
    (shouldn't it just promote to uint64_t?)
  */
  // still outputs 0, although I assume this is undefined behaviour
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(f) << '\n';
}

What is going on?

"still outputs 0, although I assume this is undefined behaviour" you cannot tell the difference between a good 0 and a bad 0. Undefined behavior is undefined.

what exactly did you expect to happen instead of what is happening?

I guess you mean you expect a warning when you shift a 8 bit wide type like uint8_t with more than (or equal to) 8 positions?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I was simply remarking that g++'s way of handling this apparently undefined behaviour was to return the answer I would expect were it defined behaviour.

Also, the fact that you use a 64-bit system does not affect the promotions, it only depends in the types in the expression. Like in f <<= 32; you have one 8-bit value and an int (which is likely 32 bits).

@DanRechtsaf I would normally have expected that, but after reading the question I linked I expected unsigned integer promotion, which means it should have worked with everything that could fit in a standard uint type. But it fails at 32.

integer promotion cannot help with overflow on <<=. The type of the lhs cannot magically change. f <<= 32 is f = (f << 32); and even if f<<32 is promoted the result is assigned to f which is a uint8_t

@BoP so would f <<= 32ULL; promote further, to uint64_t (ULL)?

uint8_t c = 5;
c <<= uint8_t(16);
...Also does noes not give a warning, so I guess integer promotion has nothing to do with it. imho indeed I would expect a warning there.


Why does "left shift count >= width of type" seemingly kick in late?

It does not "kick in late". It kicks in exactly when it intends to.

I suppose it isn't aware of __uint128_t?

It is aware of __uint128_t. Integer promotion does not promote to __int128_t.

shouldn't it just promote to uint64_t?

No.
The rules of integral promotions are https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Promotion_from_integral_types .

[...] val can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the following types that can represent all the values of its underlying type:
    int
    unsigned int
    long
    unsigned long 
    long long
    unsigned long long
    the underlying type of T


Assuming normal system, uint8_t is unsigned char and int has 32 bits. uint8_t is promoted to int, as int can represent all values. And int on your system has width 32 bits, thus the warning on 32 and 64. It is not promoted to uint64_t, but to int.

So it cannot promote multiple times? I would have assumed it would promote to unsigned int, observed that 32 bits was insufficient, and promoted again to unsigned long int or such.

I am sorry, I made a mistake - it is promoted to int, not unsigned int. What does it mean "promote multiple times"? If you promote a type with rank of int, it will stay an int.

Does this mean that uint32_t-s will simply not promote because they would go to int32_t, which cannot cover all values that uint32_t can, or to itself, which would be trivial?

There are many cases, it depends on the system. On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models LP64 data model, uint32_t is unsigned int, which has the same rank as int, so the value of such type will not be integer promoted.

@Mel • implicit promotion (conversion) happens early in the process.  Before the shift width value of the right-hand-side of that operation is taken into account.  If you want a particular promotion (casting), do it explicitly.  If you want a "safe" shift, use your own function that does the shifting safely.

In a shift operation, the integral promotions are applied to the left operand. The promotions are determined by the type of the operand and have nothing to do with the value of the right operand (the shift amount). uint8_t is always promoted to int, and the amount of the shift is never considered.
In any given C++ implementation, the promotion for each type is fixed and does not change based on any shift amounts or other operand values. Fundamentally, any integer type narrower than int is promoted to int. (There are additional rules about promoting to unsigned int or to wider types so that, for example, in a C++ implementation where unsigned short and int are the same size, unsigned short is promoted to unsigned int, and so that other types such as wchar_t are handled as desired. Those need not concern us here.)
Applying this to your examples:
uint8_t b = 5;
b <<= 8;
// 0, as expected, if slightly dubious (8 = width of type, right?)

b is promoted to int. The int 5 is shifted left 8 bits, producing 50016 = 1280. To store this in b, it is converted to uint8_t, producing 0.
uint8_t c = 5;
c <<= 16;
// 0, as expected, assuming a promotion to a larger unsigned int type

There is no promotion to unsigned int here. The fact the shift is 16 instead of 8 does not affect the promotion. c is promoted to int. The int 5 is shifted left 16 bits, producing 5000016 = 327,680. (This takes into account the fact your C++ implementation uses a 32-bit int.) To store this in c, it is converted to uint8_t, producing 0.
uint8_t d = 5;
d <<= 31;
// 0, as expected, assuming a promotion to a larger unsigned int type

As above, d is promoted to int. In C++ 2020, this produces −231. In earlier C++ versions, it was not defined. Assuming the −231, conversion to uint8_t produces 0.
uint8_t e = 5;
e <<= 64;
/*
  raises a warning, rather understandably
  (I suppose it isn't aware of __uint128_t?)
*/
// still outputs 0, although I assume this is undefined behaviour

e is promoted to int, and then the shift is undefined because the right operand is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, 32 bits. The existence of __uint128_t is irrelevant; it is not the job of the compiler to promote your operand to a type in which the shift can be performed. The rules for integral promotion are static; they do not involve what operation will be performed or the values of the operands.
uint8_t f = 5;
f <<= 32;
/*
  raises a warning for some reason
  (shouldn't it just promote to uint64_t?)
*/
// still outputs 0, although I assume this is undefined behaviour

This is the same as above; 32 is greater than or equal to the 32-bit width of int, so the behavior is not defined.
